# Two servers - different PHP performance

Tags: php, debian, apache2, settings, response

i set up a new DEBIAN root server with apache2, PHP 5.6 and mysql 5.5. I have to mention that im new in linux world so it could be that i set up the server maybe...not perfect :)

I have an old shared webserver(Apache, PHP5.5, mysql 5.5, max 100 customers) running stable with a few PHP and mysql scripts.

I wanted to change some main functions and add some modules on my own thats basically why i orderd my own root server

New server
CPU       Intel D525 MW 1.8Ghz
RAM       4 GB DDR3
HDD       2x 500 GB HDD
Debian Jessie

The old server was performing well. The response time for the main page is 400ms (onload: 2.5s)
The new server's performance is 2.9s(onload 5.5s)

The databases are exactly the same and the ftp files too.

Due to some hangs in phpmyadmin i ran a small PHP benchmark test on both servers.

Result old server

```
 --------------------------------------
 |        PHP BENCHMARK SCRIPT        |
 --------------------------------------
 Start : 2016-07-31 13:15:17
 Server : 
 PHP version : 5.5.37-nmm1
 Platform : Linux
 --------------------------------------
 test_math                 : 0.708 sec.
 test_stringmanipulation   : 0.721 sec.
 test_loops                : 0.547 sec.
 test_ifelse               : 0.352 sec.
 --------------------------------------
 Total time:               : 2.328 sec.
```

New server

```
--------------------------------------
|        PHP BENCHMARK SCRIPT        |
--------------------------------------
Start : 2016-07-31 14:01:16
Server : 
PHP version : 5.6.24-0+deb8u1
Platform : Linux
--------------------------------------
test_math                 : 9.937 sec.
test_stringmanipulation   : 9.819 sec.
test_loops                : 4.466 sec.
test_ifelse               : 2.589 sec.
--------------------------------------
Total time:               : 26.811 sec.
```

htop shows that the cpu is very busy. What could cause the big difference?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you do not have any other "heavy" processes running on the new server? That could be consuming your CPU, and making your server slow.

And what were the old server's stats(RAM,CPU...)?

Comment: im pretty sure there is no other process. The cpu load is almost zero and when i start the testscript its 100% on CPU1

Comment: I sent an email to my hoster for the information about my old server

Comment: Do you still have your old configuration files? You can try to apply them into your new server.

Comment: I can also see the PHP version has changed. I don't really know if this could affect the performance, but anyway I'll check it out,

Comment: According to [this](http://onlinephpfunctions.com/benchmarks) table, the PHP version shouldn't affect that much...